# Dragon age inquisition; the time to complete mission glitched

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

In dragon age inquisition, in the war table, I had Liliana, and the others, on a quest. all just 1 hour. then I did a certain quest and moved to skyhold. By doing that I somehow got the *time to complete* in the war table to show 999999 hours till completion. Is there any way to fix this in the console version, or am I screwed?